# How can you run two while-loops in parallel? (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop

I want to run my game a bit more efficiently. I would like to use two threads instead of one thread. Now I want to bring the two classes using a while-loop in parallel to run. But if I start the game now, the second thread will not be released until the while loop stops in the first thread.
This is my code:

```
public class Game {

     public void Game() {
         Update update;
         Render render;

         update.start();
         render.start();
     }
}

class Update implements Runnable {
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;

    @Override
    public void run() {

       while(running) {
          //Update Stuff
       }

    }

    public synchronized void start() {
         if(running)
           return;
         running = true;
         thread = new Thread(this);
         thread.start();
    }
}

class Render implements Runnable {
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;

    @Override
    public void run() {

       while(running) {
          //Render Stuff
       }

    }

    public synchronized void start() {
         if(running)
           return;
         running = true;
         thread = new Thread(this);
         thread.start();
    }
}
```

How could I start both threads at once? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just need to call `thread.start();` after initializing `thread`. You should also be careful if you're modifying the value of `running` from different threads, in which case it should be marked as `volatile`.

Comment: The code you present has much greater problems than failing to run parallel threads.  As presented, `Game` should not even compile, and neither `Runnable`'s `start()` method actually starts anything.  The behavior you describe -- *the second thread will not be released until the while loop stops in the first thread* -- absolutely **is not** exhibited, and does not seem a likely outcome of appropriate corrections.  So what is the actual question here?

Comment: Add `thread.start();` at the end of your `start` methods

Comment: I made a mistake while copying. The code is now correct.
I want to know how to use two while-loops at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public class Game {
    volatile boolean running = true;
    Thread updateThread;
    Thread renderThread;

    public void Game() {
    }

    public void start() {
        Update update = new Update(this);
        updateThread = new Thread(update);
        updateThread.start();
        Render render = new Render(this);
        renderThread = new Thread(render);
        renderThread.start();
    }

    public void waitForFinish() throws InterruptedException {
        updateThread.join();
        renderThread.join();
    }

    boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }
}

class Update implements Runnable {
    private final Game game;

    Update(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (game.isRunning()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Update");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}

class Render implements Runnable {
    private final Game game;

    Render(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (game.isRunning()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                System.out.println("Render");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}

private void test() throws InterruptedException {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.start();
    game.waitForFinish();
}
```